# How to add a hashbang to an executable Javascript file without breaking browser support?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, typescript

Is it possible to have code like this:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/node
console.log("Hello world")
```

That I can also run in the browser?

I have a script that I run locally and want to run it in the browser but right now I need to "recompile" it for the browser target only to remove the hashbang line.

I can't think of a way around it. Any ideas?

Edit: my use is that I don't want to have 2 files, as I want to be able execute the current file while working on it, and also serve it via the web. I think the solution is going to have to be to either compile it for the browser to a second file or to use an alternative to #! that plays nice with javascript.

Comment: Have one script with `#! /usr/local/bin/node` that just calls another file and use that other file in the browser?

Comment: Note that it's officially called a shebang, you might find better search result of you search on that keyword

Comment: Thanks @Ferrybig, but can you clarify what you mean by "officially"?

Comment: @Breck Simply compare the [search trends from Google](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=shebang,hashbang) and you'll find that usage of the term `shebang` vastly dwarfs usage of the term `hashbang`. Both terms are technically correct, but `shebang` is the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only ever use bash, you can take advantage of one feature (?!) of bash: [bash executes scripts without a shebang using bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Scripts). Other shells may leave it to the OS, which would usually use `/bin/sh` instead. For example:

```
bash-5.0$ echo 'echo $1 $BASH_VERSION' > foo.sh
bash-5.0$ for sh in sh bash dash ksh zsh; do $sh -c "./foo.sh $sh"; done
sh 3.2.57(1)-release
bash 5.0.7(1)-release
dash 3.2.57(1)-release
ksh
zsh 3.2.57(1)-release
```

(`/bin/sh` being a link to an old version of bash here on macOS.)

So, you could have a file like this:

```js
///usr/local/bin/node <(tail -n +1 "$0"); exit $?
console.log("Hello world")
```

If you run this in a browser, or other means of running JavaScript, the first line should be ignored as a comment.

If you run this as a script in bash, the first line tells it to run `///usr/local/bin/node`, using process substitution with `tail` to feed the rest of the file to node, and then exits:

```
bash-5.0$ cat foo.js
///usr/local/bin/node <(tail -n +1 "$0"); exit $?
console.log("Hello world")
bash-5.0$ ./foo.js
Hello world
```

This trick might work with ksh as well. The `///` at the beginning of the path shouldn't cause problems - three or more `/` at the start of a path are equivalent to a single `/`.

But I would strongly encourage you to use a wrapper script instead, as suggested by the comments.

Comment: This is the kind of clever hack I was looking for! I just did: "///usr/local/bin/node filename; exit;" which ensured I got the correct cwd. Now, if you excuse me I'm going to add a build step and do things the "proper" way. But happy there is a way.